# Freeing memory for struct.name (debug error: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED)

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, free

I'm creating dynamic arrays with the length of a name inputed by the user, but when I want to `free()` the memory allocated with `malloc()` it's giving me a "Debug error"

```
typedef struct
{
    char *nombre;
    float nota;
} tficha;

tficha leeFicha() 
{
    char nombreTam[100]; 
    int tamNombre;      
    tficha ficha;       
    scanf("%s",nombreTam); 
    tamNombre=strlen(nombreTam); 
    ficha.nombre=(char *)malloc(tamNombre*sizeof(char)); 
    strcpy(ficha.nombre,nombreTam); 
    free(ficha.nombre); // Here is giving me a Debug Error (HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#166) at 0x0065C450. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.)
    return ficha;       
}
```

How can I free `ficha.nombre` without errors?

Comment: There is no need to cast `malloc` & friends in C, nor is it recommended in any way.

Comment: OT: To avoid overflowing the target buffer while scanning do `scanf("%Ns",nombreTam);` with `N` being the size of the buffer `-1`. So here: `scanf("%99s",nombreTam);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correctly finding the length of the string:

```
tamNombre=strlen(nombreTam);
```

but when you allocated the memory:

```
ficha.nombre=(char *)malloc(tamNombre*sizeof(char));
```

you allocate only enough memory for the characters of the string, and not the terminating NUL. You want:

```
ficha.nombre=(char *)malloc(tamNombre*sizeof(char)+1);
```

But as `char` is guaranteed by the C standard to be of size 1, you can write:

```
ficha.nombre=(char *)malloc(tamNombre+1);
```

And as [you don't need to cast the return of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?noredirect=1&lq=1), the simplest is:

```
ficha.nombre=malloc(tamNombre+1);
```

Without this change, the `strcpy` is writing beyond the end of the allocated memory, which is probably what is causing your problem.

However, it also seems peculiar that you are doing:

```
free(ficha.nombre);
```

within this function anyway. That guarantees that the `ficha` `struct` has a pointer to deallocated memory - i.e. you effectively 'forget' the number as soon as it is entered. Rather you should be `free()`ing `ficha.nombre` when you have done with the `ficha` `struct` - presumably the caller needs the value after all.

Comment: Well yes all fine, but *please* drop those useless casts.

Comment: @alk indeed. Fixed.

Comment: OK, now it's working but now it's not returning the struct, how can I return the struct and free the memory?

Comment: @Albermonte remove the `free()`, and free the memory after you have actually finished with the `struct`.

Comment: @Albermonte: This would be another question ... :-)